# When using `dvdbackup`, is it true that 64GB DVDs exist?

Tags: linux, backup, dvd, iso-image

I rip the DVDs that I own to my hard disk using a straight-up 1:1 copy, ie to an ISO image. This works great usually, but for this specific DVD that I'm presently trying to rip, I'm being told that the DVD is literally 64GB in size. It's definitely not a BluRay disc, and I don't even have a BluRay drive, so that possibility is ruled out.

I'm not having any problems playing back the DVD file in VLC. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 64bit. How on earth could it be a 64GB DVD?!? Isn't the max capacity of a DVD around 8 gigabytes? I don't even think that BluRay discs hold 64GB of data!

### EDIT

When I ripped the DVD with `dvdbackup`, I kept receiving the following errors:

```
Error reading VTS_15_0.VOB at block 3391
padding 193 blocks
Error reading VTS_16_0.VOB at block 1999
padding 49 blocks
Error reading VTS_16_0.VOB at block 3391
padding 193 blocks
Error reading VTS_17_0.VOB at block 1999
padding 49 blocks
Error reading VTS_17_0.VOB at block 3391
padding 193 blocks
Error reading VTS_18_0.VOB at block 1999
padding 49 blocks
Error reading VTS_18_0.VOB at block 3391
padding 193 blocks
Error reading VTS_19_0.VOB at block 1999
padding 49 blocks
```

It seems like it's looping over the same blocks over and over again or having problems in each VOB file at the same point? That looks like a red flag to me, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A DVD will never be that large. What could happen is that the disk advertises itself as being larger than it actually is (weird copy protection scheme), or that your OS has a bug reading that DVD, which happens more frequently that it may seem (I once got a 1 TB CD-R...).

Try to rip it anyway. The worst that could happen is that you fill your disk, which should be pretty easy to recover from.

Answer (score 3):

In the VIDEO_TS folder you will find several files called VTS_xx-y.VOB or VTS_xx-y.IFO. These are arranged in sets, where xx is the number of the title set, from 00 to 99.

Typically for each title set there will be a few files, eg VTS_02 may have files like

```
VTS_02_0.IFO         86016    84.00 KiB
VTS_02_0.VOB     258586624   246.61 MiB
VTS_02_1.VOB    1073739776  1024.00 MiB
VTS_02_2.VOB    1073739776  1024.00 MiB
VTS_02_3.VOB    1073739776  1024.00 MiB
VTS_02_4.VOB    1073739776  1024.00 MiB
VTS_02_5.VOB     866340864   826.21 MiB
```

The .IFO files are information files which contain information about which titles are in the set (there can be 99 titles in all on a DVD, and also 99 title sets - note, titles and title sets are not the same thing at all). A DVD may have eg 9 title sets with 27 titles spread around them.

Each title set must contain at least one title, and usually contains more than one, so there are usually more titles that title sets.

The main feature is only uniquely identified by its title, not by the title set which contains that title. A DVD player can look at all the .IFO files in all the title sets in order to find all the titles, although this information is also supposed to be in the VIDEO_TS.IFO file.

OK, when they try to stop people ripping DVDs, and sometimes for more legitimate reasons, the same .VOB files may be listed in the directory listing in several title sets, but accessed differently, eg different audio tracks etc. according to the information in the .IFO file for that set.

This means that the same 1.1GB .VOBs may appear several times in the directory listing with different VTS numbers - they are a bit like links to files rather than files themselves.

Not being very clever, many programs try to reproduce the directory listing - and rip the same set of 1.1GB files several times. This leads to very large, like 64GB, VIDEO_TS folder rips even though the DVD itself only holds about 8 GB.

For dvdbackup the best way to avoid this is to tell it the title you want to rip, eg

dvdbackup --title=24 --start=1 --end=17

where 1 and 17 are the first and last chapters of the movie, and 24 is the title which is played as the main feature. You don't actually need to include the start and end numbers, but it helps.

If you can play the DVD in eg movie player, zine or VLC they will tell you the right numbers to use - the title number appears in the window title bar when the main feature is being played, the chapter numbers can be found easily enough in the usual places.

Incidentally this is why you get the same errors at the same places - it is reading the same lots of data ("files") several times.

Sometimes as an anti-ripping measure they put deliberate errors in, and the correct "link" is made to somewhere after the errors, not to the beginning of the data - so only the correct "link" will work, and if you try to play the files from the wrong link they won't play. Alternatively the deliberate error is in a place which doesn't get used in normal play for that title, eg if the german audio isn't being used.

This can get very complex, but the resulting DVD has to play on DVD players - which limits what they can do.

HTH.

Comment: See https://moral.net.au/writing/2015/10/10/backing_up_dvds/ for a write-up of the copy protection mechanisms involved.

Answer (score 1):

Dig through the DVD to check which files/directories are taking up the disk space

Use `du -shc *`

Also, did you try checking the DVD on a non-*nix system ?

Comment: Here's a dump of DVD file sizes: http://pastebin.com/WNVqrNgm

Comment: And no, I don't have access to a non-*nix system.

Comment: @TKKocheran that's crazy. Maybe it's a similar issue as on Windows: There's a "file size" and a "file size on the filesystem". You can blow the normal file size out of proportions and it will still not be that big on the file system. Maybe some kind of copy protection like others suggested

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting the video in uncompressed format, that can blow up enormously the size of the video.

Uncompressed format does not in this case gain you much improvement in quality, since the source was already compressed on the DVD.

Blu-ray disc with dual layer can go up to 50 GB, although 100 GB have also been demonstrated.

Comment: He said he was making ISO's, so no compression change.

Comment: Yes, goal here is 1:1 copying.

Comment: @Xr: I would like first to know what his extraction software was, and whether the resulting 64GB iso was playable.

Comment: Haven't actually finished a rip yet. Using `dvdbackup` then converting into an iso with `genisoimage`.

Comment: Just finished a rip and it definitely looks like it's putting out 64 gb of data. Please see the edited question above with some of the errors it put out.

Comment: IMHO it can be : (1) bad DVD, (2) encrypted DVD, (3) bug in dvdbackup. The only way to check is to try it elsewhere and/or with another ripper. Also, check the DVD visually for scratches.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add this entry (if its for real) into Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD saying ***"Really Really Rare"*** just below the following below the picture

> 17.08 GB (double-sided, double-layer – rare)

Comment: lol, could it possibly be some DVD obsfucation technique to deter people like me who like to make backups? It's a single-sided dvd, I have serious doubts that it's really that big. However, on playing most of the VOB files, it seems legit. Implausible, but legit. And who has 64gb of data to put on a simple movie DVD like this anyway!?!

Comment: Yes it is some kind of protection I guess. Try looking around what software can give you a workaround with this. (There are a lot of 'clickety-click' ones out there.)

Comment: Any recommendations? I'm on linux, so I'm using `dvdbackup`. I can try using `dd`, but I assume that if it's crazy enough to fake its size, it's probably crazy enough to have CSS to prevent a `dd`.

Comment: try ogmrip, never failed me yet.

Comment: Will do. See new edits above describing some errors I saw in the rip with `dvdbackup` last night, interesting stuff.